# Post's criterion for a single operation

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, logic

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while but my progress is modest.

Let $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ be a logical function. Show that the signature $\langle f\rangle$ is complete if and only if $f$ does not lie in $T_0,T_1$ and $S$.

The arrow from the left to the right is evident due to Post's criterion. From the right to the left is harder: I could deduced if $f(0,...,0)=1$ and $f(1,..,1)=0$ then f is not monotonous. It would be enough to prove that f is not in $L$ but I don't know how.

Thank's in advance! :-)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof by contradiction. Suppose that $f\in L.$ Then $f=\bigoplus\limits_{j=1}^kx_{i_j}\oplus\varepsilon,$ where $\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\},\:i_1<\dots<i_k$ and $\varepsilon\in\{0,1\}.$

As you've noticed, $f(0,\dots,0)=1$. This implies $\varepsilon=1.$ Since $f(1,\dots,1)=0,$ the number of monomials of first degree $k$ is odd, i.e. $k=2l+1$. Now we prove the following lemma:

**Lemma.** $\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{2l+1}x_i\oplus\varepsilon\in S.$

**Proof.** Let $(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_{2l+1})\in\{0,1\}^{2l+1}.$ Then $$f(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_{2l+1})=\delta\equiv\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2l+1}\delta_i+\varepsilon\mod2$$ and $$f(1-\delta_1,\dots,1-\delta_{2l+1})=\delta'\equiv\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2l+1}(1-\delta_i)+\varepsilon\mod2.$$

Sum these two equalities: $$\delta+\delta'\equiv\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2l+1}(\delta_i+1-\delta_i)+2\varepsilon\mod2.$$

But $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2l+1}(\delta_i+1-\delta_i)+2\varepsilon=2l+1+2\varepsilon\equiv1\mod2.$ So, $\delta\ne\delta'$ for each $(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_{2l+1})$ and $f\notin S.\qquad\square$

The contradiction. We obtain $f\notin L.$

Comment: Why is the number of monomials of first degree is odd?

Comment: Let $x_{i_1}=\dots=x_{i_k}=1$. Then $x_{i_1}\oplus\dots\oplus x_{i_k}\oplus 1=i_k\oplus1=0.$ So, $i_k\not\equiv 0\mod2.$

Comment: Thank you, i got it :-D